# _BitScanForward _BitScanForward64 missing (VS2017) Snappy

Tags: c++, visual-c++, x86, bit-manipulation, intrinsics

I'm trying to compile snappy ( https://bitbucket.org/robertvazan/snappy-visual-cpp) with VS2017. I can't pull this off with VS2015 also; - I've tried in command prompt (msbuild) and through the visual studio IDE; it can't recognize both _BitScanForward and_BitScanForward64. If it didn't recognize just one I would figure I've chosen wrong build mode (x86/x64) but seems like both are missing. I made sure to run the correct version of command prompt when building with msbuild.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <intrin.h>
```

was missing.

Comment: Non-MSVC compilers (GCC/clang) define their non-SIMD intrinsics in `<x86intrin.h>`.  For SIMD stuff (SSE/AVX/AVX-512), you can portably use `<immintrin.h>`, but intrinsics for scalar stuff aren't as portable and some compilers put them in different headers.