# Intel Intrinsics to find positions of matching characters in a string?

Tags: x86, sse, intrinsics

The problem I have right now, is figuring out which intrinsic is best suited for the job.

I am attempting to parse a header as fast as possible. I check the first 16 bytes of the header with a few masks to get the METHOD first. The one I was recommended to use is `_mm_cmpeq_epi8` and then load the mask with `_mm_movemask_epi8`.

Now I need to check the index of space   characters to get the route. For example,

```
GET /this/is/a/route?id=777 HTTP/1.1\r\n
```

index 3, and 27.

Which intrinsic would be best suited for the job?

Comment: bit-scan one the movemask results, with an intrinsic for `tzcnt` or for the old `bsf`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Are you saying to continue using cmpeq_epi8 with a mask of all spaces, and then use bsf or tzcnt to somehow extract the index?

Comment: yes. `bsf` gives you the position of the lowest `1` bit.  So it's not "somehow", it just does it.  (Although to find every space, you'd have to loop through each vector with the clear-lowest-set-bit bithack, `mask &= mask-1` (which can compile to [blsr](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/blsr) if you have BMI1)

Comment: I'll play with it a bit. I'm not really seeing how to do that. @PeterCordes

Comment: I can't seem to import bsf. Am I missing something. `#include <nmmintrin.h>
#include <immintrin.h>
` and none of the bsf's here are found. https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#!=undefined&text=bsf&expand=464  @PeterCordes

Comment: See [Find position of first (lowest) set bit in 32-bit number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58439198).  `__builtin_ctz` should work, or if you're only using it on non-zero inputs then `_mm_tzcnt_32` works, too, even on CPUs with BMI1, if you're using ICC or MSVC.

Comment: Or if you're using MSVC, [\_BitScanForward \_BitScanForward64 missing (VS2017) Snappy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48998618) - MSVC defines `_BitScanForward` in `<intrin.h>`

Comment: With C++20, `std::countr_zero`.